# Tbody tag in xpath produced by fire bug

Tags: ruby, xpath, firebug, hpricot

I'm trying to extract some data from online htmls using ruby hpricot library. I use the firefox extension fire bug to get the xpath of a selected item.

There's always the extra tbody tag present in the produced xpath expression. In some cases, I must remove the tbody tag from the expression to obtain the results while in other cases, I must keep the tag to get the results.

I just can't figure out when to keep the tbody tag and when not to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In order to take into account and avoid this problem, use XPath expressions of the following kind**:

```
 /locStep1/locStep2/.../table/YourSubExpression
|
 /locStep1/locStep2/.../table/tbody/YourSubExpression
```

**If the `table` doesn't have a `tbody` child**, then the second argument of the union operator (`|`) selects no nodes and the first argument of the union selects the wanted nodes.

**Alternatively, if the `table` *has* a `tbody` child**, then the first argument of the union operator selects no nodes and the second argument of the union selects the wanted nodes.

**The end result**: in both cases the wanted nodes are selected

Answer (score 1):

Well with HTML 4 or with XHTML served as text/html the parser always infers a `tbody` element to wrap `tr` elements in that are direct children of an `table` element in the parsed mark up, that is why inside the browser DOM a HTML `table` always has a `tbody` containing any `tr` elements and a tool like Firebug gives you path that works against the Firefox/Mozilla DOM. I don't know what kind of parser your Ruby library uses, perhaps it uses an XML parser for XHTML documents and an XML parser does not infer `tbody` elements for `table` elements.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 always adds the tbody element if its not there explicitly - it's part of the repair strategy for dealing with invalid HTML. If you want to cope with a variety of environments, using table//tr might make sense.