# DOMXPath Return Zero

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath

Im trying to extract some information from a website. The info I need is contained in a table, I have already created a query to find it. When using the console from Chrome I can see the table I need is returned by the expression. But when I set up the PHP code, the query returns zero.

This is from the Chrome console

[image]

And this is my PHP code

```
$ch = curl_init($domain);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($cl);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$table = $xpath->query("//div[@id='content_fmainplace']//form/table/tbody/tr[15]//table");
echo $table->length;
```

Any ideas? What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried not suppressing error messages?

Comment: really hard to guess from here, care to share the site link?

Comment: @kevinabelita This is the link, the information I need is under the 2.1 Section http://app.cfe.gob.mx/Aplicaciones/CCFE/Tarifas/Tarifas/tarifas_casa.asp?Tarifa=DACTAR1E&Temporada4=Verano&Anio=2014&imprime=&Periodo=4&mes2=a+septiembre.&mes=1

Comment: @elgranchuy what an html structure of a site, a pain! which part of the 2.1 section? the title and its contents?

Comment: @kevinabelita I know, that's something I had to deal with everyday :(.
anyway... I think I found the 'error'. It seems like the tbody is not working or is not being detected somehow. I don't know if Chrome/Firefox adds the tbody tag to every table or DOMXPath is not detecting it. I changed my query to `//div[@id='content_fmainplace']//form/table//tr[15]//table` and its working now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tbody tag in xpath produced by fire bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203619/tbody-tag-in-xpath-produced-by-fire-bug)

Comment: @elgranchuy  Based on your proposed solution, the problem boils down to the question I just linked to. The answers there might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You really dont need to target the div. Just target the `id` of the table instead. Consider this example: [**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DoB9F8)

```
$domain = 'http://app.cfe.gob.mx/Aplicaciones/CCFE/Tarifas/Tarifas/tarifas_casa.asp?Tarifa=DACTAR1E&Temporada4=Verano&Anio=2014&imprime=&Periodo=4&mes2=a+septiembre.&mes=1';
$ch = curl_init($domain);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($cl);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// target the title
$title = $values = $xpath->query('//table[@id="Table1"]/tr[1]/td[1]/form/table/tr[14]')->item(0)->nodeValue; // title rows
$rows = $xpath->query('//table[@id="Table1"]/tr[1]/td[1]/form/table/tr[15]/td/table/tr');
$row_values = array();

// process td elements
foreach($rows as $index => $row) {
    foreach($row->childNodes as $td) {
        // clean up
        $row_values[$index][] = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', trim($td->nodeValue));
    }
    // clean up again
    $row_values[$index] = array_filter($row_values[$index]);
}    

?>

<!-- print them -->
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
<table cellpadding="10">
<?php foreach($row_values as $values): ?>
    <tr><?php foreach($values as $value): ?>
        <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah I did saw the table id but the thing is that this link is for January's rates for section 1E, if you change the section to a different one 1A,1B,1C or 1D the code changes a little bit, and in some of them the table ID is missing. I notice that the query I used works for all of them.